# Expansion by a metallic rod

Tags: thermodynamics

Suppose that the maximum expansion experienced by a $12.0m$ iron rod at a temperature of $48°C$ is $0.396cm$. Does this mean that , if the rod expands by $0.396cm$ , it will expand by $\frac{0.396}{2}cm$ in each direction ? Is the linear expansion in a metallic rod uniform on both sides ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, although one should be careful to say that if one end of the rod is held fixed all the expansion is on the other side. If *both* ends of the rod are held fixed then there's a force exerted on whatever is holding the rod, as well as internal stress in the rod.